# How to get HTTP headers

Tags: objective-c, http, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

How do you retrieve all HTTP headers from a `NSURLRequest` in Objective-C?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This falls under the easy, but not obvious class of iPhone programming problems. Worthy of a quick post:

The headers for an HTTP connection are included in the `NSHTTPURLResponse` class. If you have an `NSHTTPURLResponse` variable you can easily get the headers out as a `NSDictionary` by sending the allHeaderFields message.

For synchronous requests — not recommended, because they block — it’s easy to populate an `NSHTTPURLResponse`:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mobileorchard.com"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: url];
NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: &response error: nil];
if ([response respondsToSelector:@selector(allHeaderFields)]) {
NSDictionary *dictionary = [response allHeaderFields];
NSLog([dictionary description]);
}
```

With an asynchronous request you have to do a little more work. When the callback `connection:didReceiveResponse:` is called, it is passed an `NSURLResponse` as the second parameter. You can cast it to an `NSHTTPURLResponse` like so:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
 NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;    
if ([response respondsToSelector:@selector(allHeaderFields)]) {
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [httpResponse allHeaderFields];
    NSLog([dictionary description]);
}
}
```

Comment: If you just want to fetch http response header then post HEAD request. HEAD request will not fetch body of response.
Example - Set Http Method type in request. 
NSMutableURLRequest *mutableRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
mutableRequest.HTTPMethod = @"HEAD";

Comment: Why we should cast NSURLResponse to an NSHTTPURLResponse ?

Comment: This does *not* log all headers sent in the request! If you set additional headers to the NSURLSessionConfiguration, those will not be logged. I haven't found yet how to retrieve them from the response...

Answer (score 4):

Given `NSURLConnection` is deprecated from iOS 9, you can use an `NSURLSession` to get MIME type information from an `NSURL` or `NSURLRequest`.

You ask the session to retrieve the URL, then upon receiving the first `NSURLResponse` (which contains MIME type information) in a delegate callback you cancel the session to prevent it downloading the whole URL.

Here is some bare bones Swift code that does it:

```
/// Use an NSURLSession to request MIME type and HTTP header details from URL.
///
/// Results extracted in delegate callback function URLSession(session:task:didCompleteWithError:).
///
func requestMIMETypeAndHeaderTypeDetails() {
    let url = NSURL.init(string: "https://google.com/")
    let urlRequest = NSURLRequest.init(URL: url!)

    let session = NSURLSession.init(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.ephemeralSessionConfiguration(), delegate: self, delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())

    let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest)
    dataTask.resume()
}

//MARK: NSURLSessionDelegate methods

func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionResponseDisposition) -> Void) {

    // Cancel the rest of the download - we only want the initial response to give us MIME type and header info.
    completionHandler(NSURLSessionResponseDisposition.Cancel)
}

func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: NSError?)
{       
    var mimeType: String? = nil
    var headers: [NSObject : AnyObject]? = nil


    // Ignore NSURLErrorCancelled errors - these are a result of us cancelling the session in 
    // the delegate method URLSession(session:dataTask:response:completionHandler:).
    if (error == nil || error?.code == NSURLErrorCancelled) {

        mimeType = task.response?.MIMEType

        if let httpStatusCode = (task.response as? NSHTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode {
            headers = (task.response as? NSHTTPURLResponse)?.allHeaderFields

            if httpStatusCode >= 200 && httpStatusCode < 300 {
                // All good

            } else {
                // You may want to invalidate the mimeType/headers here as an http error
                // occurred so the mimeType may actually be for a 404 page or
                // other resource, rather than the URL you originally requested!
                // mimeType = nil
                // headers = nil
            }
        }
    }

    NSLog("mimeType = \(mimeType)")
    NSLog("headers = \(headers)")

    session.invalidateAndCancel()
}
```

I've packaged similar functionality in the [URLEnquiry](https://github.com/github-user32/URLEnquiry/) project at github which makes it a bit easier to make in-line queries for MIME types and HTTP headers. [URLEnquiry.swift](https://github.com/github-user32/URLEnquiry/blob/master/URLEnquiry/URLEnquiry.swift) is the file of interest that could be dropped into your own project.

Answer (score 2):

YourViewController.h

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *yourWebView;
@end
```

YourViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //Set the UIWebView delegate to your view controller
    self.yourWebView.delegate = self;

    //Request your URL
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://website.com/your-page.php"]];

    [self.legalWebView loadRequest:request];
}

//Implement the following method
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
    NSLog(@"%@",[webView.request allHTTPHeaderFields]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift version using Alamofire for efficiency. This is what worked for me:

```
Alamofire.request(YOUR_URL).responseJSON {(data) in

if let val = data.response?.allHeaderFields as? [String: Any] {
      print("\(val)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use AFHTTPSessionManager framework and get The headers after a request or during,  example below (to get all keys):

NSHTTPURLResponse *reponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)task.response;
NSLog(@"%@", [reponseHeaders allHeaderFields]);

To access a specific key:  [reponseHeaders allHeaderFields][@"someKey"]

Refer to:
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/3688