# Add custom http header request swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I have iOS8 swift application which communicate to web service URL. However, I do not like to have access to my web service from device that is not mobile device. How can I achive this using iOS8 swift application. In fact I need HTTP header, that have device-specific information using NSURLConnection.

Comment: May be this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236317/how-to-get-http-headers

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you create a `NSMutableURLRequest` and then use the method:

```
request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```